# how to display an alert after redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, php

login form (index.php) was already created. when form is submitted username and password are passed in to another page (login-controller.php). after verifying, if username or password is incorrect user was redirected to login form(index.php) after display the alert box in login-controller.php.but i want to display an alert box like "invalid login credentials" after redirect to login form(index.php). how can i solve this. code of login-controller.php are given bellow.

```html
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: ../service/index.php');
}

include '../include/conn.php'; //database connection

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["username"] && $_POST["password"])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);
        $password = md5($password);
        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = $conn->query($sqli);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: ../service/index.php');
        } else {
            include '../include/bootstrap.php'; //bootstrap js and css
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Oops!</strong> Invalid Login Credentials.</div>';
            echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'index.php';\",3000);</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add some GET parameters to the redirect url, detect it  in the login page and display the notification

Comment: Its a bad practice to wrote javascript code in PHP rather redirect to login page with some query string and on login page write code to check if that query string is error then display the popup.

Comment: you can use session or local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using session variables you can display alerts:

```
$_SESSION['alerts'][] = "Test Alert";
$_SESSION['alerts'][] = "Another Test Alert";
```

Then in your config, or any other .php file that gets executed on every page that you have ( If you have a templating system, do that in the template) do this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['alerts'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['alerts'] as $alertmessage){
        echo '<div class="alert">' . $alertmessage . '</div>';
    }
}
```